# How can I use the ffi package to use c++ in my flutter app?

Tags: c++, flutter, cross-compiling, elf, dart-ffi

Right now I am trying to implement the mediapipe c++ library into my flutter app. At the beginning I wrote a simple function with a printf() function in it in c++ to try to to run it in flutter.

I compiled as follows:

`g++ -shared -o produce_landmarks.so -fPIC produce_landmarks.cpp`

I put the compiled shared .so file into each following structur folder:
android/app/src/main/jniLibs

- /arm64-v8a
- /armeabi-v7a
- /x86
- /x86_64

Unfortunately I got an bad ELF error. Probably because I didn't compiled it for the correct processor architecture.

`"data/app/.../lib/arm64/produce_landmarks.so" has bad ELF magic: 4d5a9000" //on phone "/data/app/.../lib/x86_64/produce_landmarks.so" has bad ELF magic: 4d5a9000 // on emulator`

But do I really need to compile the c++ code, which is right now a simple function with a printf() function into different architectures? If that's the case then how can I do it?

I would like to know what the exact steps are to run

- a simple c++ function
- the mediapipe c++ library
  in flutter.

I am asking because I am just confused of the many ways that the ffi package was being used in youtube. Do I need to use ffigen? I saw many people create plugins? But I don't think that I need that because I don't want to access native language features like the camera and so one.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: It's generally advisable to create a plugin, just to keep the ffi code out of your main project. (Plugins aren't just for native interaction, they're also useful for ffi separation.) Also, no, there's no need to use ffigen - until it becomes enough of a bore creating the stubs manually. The easiest way to get ffi to work is to let Flutter compile the C/C++ for you. Remember that ffi can only talk directly to C, so you'll need a C wrapper around any C++ code or library, which you will write. Let Flutter build that for you.

Comment: Did something [here](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) cause you to ask this question? Official resources should be consulted alongside any youtube tutorials. I have found that *most* programming tutorials on YouTube are not good.

Comment: If you have 56 minutes, consider watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8JD8hHkBMc You might find that you could wrap mediapipe in a similar way to oboe. Though why wouldn't you use the Android and iOS versions through a regular plugin?

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you I thought that it was pretty strange that I had to think about how to cross compile it manually with linaro for example. I will definetely watch your video to deepen my knowledge, as it seems to be insufficient right now :)

After asking bing AI I could find a package that implements the Android and IOS plugin.

https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit

Next time I better stick to the documentation than ChatGPT telling me to do weird stuff.

Comment: @sweenish You’re totally right. I was just overwhelmed by all these topics, which seemed to overflow into each other and searched for a shortcut. But nonetheless, I should have taken my time to understand the documentation, so that I would know how it works and understand why I would need certain things.